# libuv and uv_try_write: why multiple buffers?

Tags: c, libuv

Consider the documentation of [`uv_try_write`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#api) (the same applies for `uv_write` and `uv_write2` as well).
The declaration is:

```
int uv_try_write(uv_stream_t* handle, const uv_buf_t bufs[], unsigned int nbufs)
```

Where [`uv_buf_t`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html#c.uv_buf_t) is a data structure that has at least the following fields:

- `char* uv_buf_t.base`
- `size_t uv_buf_t.len`

I'm quite sure I'm missing something here.

What's the reason for which one should submit more than one `uv_buf_t` structure instead of a *bigger* one?
In other terms, if I have 100 `char` to write out, why should I submit 10 `uv_buf_t` containing each 10 `char` instead of a `uv_buf_t` containing 100 `char`?

It would be helpful a *real world* example in which such a choice makes sense, for I can't figure out it while reading the documentation.

Comment: For my understanding, many buffers means different "messages", bigger buff means bigger message length.

Comment: @LPs Anyway, different messages are generated at different times, so I could send the first one when it is available and there is no actual reason to wait for the next one. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can think about a "service" that is responsible for sending messages queued by different tasks/threads, for example.

Comment: @LPs A service that has to implement once more the Nagle's algorithm to decide when it's the time to deliver everything? Otherwise, once woken up, why couldn't it invoke `uv_try_write` more than once? Anyway I got your point, not sure it's the reason, but it makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications probably use a single one, but since `writev` is a thing we expose it in the try variant as well. Imagine an application which behaves as a proxy, and gets data in multiple packets which it then needs to relay. Sensing all buffers belonging to the same packet in a single go limits the syscalls to 1, instead of having to allocate space for all buffers, then copying over the content just to call `write`.

You can read more about the approach here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you perform formatted I/O, all you are doing is concatenating a bunch of small strings.

Think about what is happening under the hood when you write something like

```
fprintf(stdout, "Hello, %s!\n", getenv("USER"));
```

This could be implemented (ignoring the multiple evaluation of `getenv`) as:

```
struct iovec bufs[3] = {{"Hello, ", 7}, {getenv("USER"), strlen(getenv("USER"))}, {"!\n", 2}};
writev(STDOUT_FILENO, bufs, 3);
```

(in practice, `FILE` operations are a little more complicated - perhaps unnecessarily so - but most cases *are* this simple).

Allowing multiple buffers to be specified directly means that you don't have to waste process time (or source code complexity) allocating a single buffer to hold them all before writing.

---

Also, have you ever run an compiler under `make -j` such that its output gets hugely messed up? That is generally caused because they do *not* do this - instead they emit several individual `write`s and they get mixed with writes from parallel processes, rather than emitting each line during a single syscall.